# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1928

Tags: identificación-de-término

There is no need to discuss both the years 1927 and 1931 (1929 is similar) as they both have an existing note:

> En el puesto de Puente Genil finió el año.

In terms of the debate about finó and finió ... many have said that the handwriting looks like finó but that it would not be grammatically correct because it pertains to death.

This would make sense in English:

> He was at the Puente Genil post until the end of the year.

In that sense the word finó fits because the year does have an **end**. Let me know what you think.

---

Here is the note for 1928:

[image]

[image]

Transcription so far:

> Con fecha 24 Enero le fueron comedidos por S. E. El Director Gral
> [General] del Cuerpo 15 días de permiso para Granada de los cuales no
> hizo uso por haber manifestado no le xxx ueees eirio. Prestando sus
> servicios en el puesto de Puente Genil finio el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

The translation so far:

> On 24 January he was granted 15 days leave for Granada by H. E. The
> Director General of the Corps, which he did not make use of as he
> stated that he did not wish to take it. Serving in the post of Puente
> Genil at the end of the year.
>
> The Major Commander

For some reason the translation does no show the xxx words so I don't know how accurate it is, even thought it makes sense.

---

As for that word at the top left... I assume it is Dmas, being an abbreviation for Ademas. Only a guess. We discussed that term on a previous question.

---

#### Translation

This is the updated translation based on the answer:

> On 24th January, H.E. the Director General of the Corps granted him 15
> days leave for Granada, which he did not use as he stated that he did
> not need it. He served at the Puente Genil post at the end of the
> year.
>
> The Major Commander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Con fecha 24 Enero le fueron **concedidos** por S. E. el Director Gral [General] del Cuerpo 15 días de permiso para Granada de los cuales no hizo uso por haber manifestado no le **era necesario**. Prestando sus servicios en el puesto de Puente Genil finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

DeepL seems to have done a good job of guessing the xxx words, as the translation is mostly correct.

The word on the top left of the second image is **Años**: it is just a header for the years that always appear on that margin.

Comment: Thank for your answer and clarifications. I have updated the question with the tweaked translation.